# How to generate a table based on coordinates in perl?

Tags: perl, command-line

I have a big file containing a number of spots, a position and a set of coordinates like:.

```
no  pos/neg cordinates
1     +     1    3
2     +     5    8
3     -    10   12
```

What I want to do is first to convert the length of intervals to point ( 1-3 -> to 1 2 3 )
next in a new column for each time that I have (+) to add 1, -1 when I have (-) and zero 0 when I am outside of the coordinate and in another column to have the sum of the second column as the table below

```
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  3
4  0  3
5  1  4
6  1  5
7  1  6
8  1  7
9  0  7
10 -1 -6
11 -1 -5
12 -1 -4
```

I read that I can only do this by using hashes but as I'm still new in Perl so I don't know how to deal with it. Initially, I was thinking of using command prompt to generate 3 files and then to `paste` them like in one but there so technical difficulties.

For example, with `sed 1 12` I can generate the first column but I cannot use sed for linking the 2ond and 3rd even if know how to calculate them

```
awk 'BEGIN {v=0} {if ($2=="-") {v=v-1} else {v=v+1}; $4=v; print}'
    | awk '{print $0 "\t" (c+=$4"1")}'
```

It is not nessesery to use perl so If anyone knows how to link those commands I will be obligated.

Comment: Are the coordinates ordered in the input file?

Comment: yes, they are!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code reads data, skips header, split line on spaces, defines increment value and calculates sum

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $sum   = 0;                          # sum 
my $count = 1;                          # line counter

while(<DATA>){                          # read data
    next if /pos/;                      # skip header
    my($n,$p,$a,$b) = split '\s+';      # split on spaces

    say $_ . "\t0\t$sum" for $count..$a-1; # gap block

    my $i;                              # '+'/'-' increment
    $i =  1 if $p eq '+';               # incremet  by  1 if '+'
    $i = -1 if $p eq '-';               # decrement by -1 if '-'

    for ($a..$b) {                      # pos point coordinates
        $sum += $i;                     # calculate sum
        say "$_\t$i\t$sum";             # output
    }
    $count=$b+1;                        # increment counter for next line
}

__DATA__
no  pos/neg cordinates
1     +     1    3
2     +     5    8
3     -    10   12
```

Output

```
1       1       1
2       1       2
3       1       3
4       0       3
5       1       4
6       1       5
7       1       6
8       1       7
9       0       7
10      -1      6
11      -1      5
12      -1      4
```

Comment: This assumes the first coordinate of the first entry will be `1` and/or that the leading numbers need to be backfilled from `1`. Might be desirable, or not.

Comment: Tip: Avoid using `$a` and `$b` as lexicals. It will break `sort` and some subs.

Comment: This piece of code does not assume sort of any kind, `$a` and `$b` can be anything else -- these was chosen as first letters of alphabet which came to mind, they could be `$start` and `$end` .

Comment: I know. And like I said, you shouldn't do that. It's a bad habit because they're effectively special variables. It will come back to bite you.

Comment: ikegami -- never heard anything so childish... hahahaha.... Am I coder or `moon shuttle conductor`?

Comment: Neither, apparently? Everything about CS is about readability and maintainability. That's why we scope variables. That's why we write clean code. That's why we strive for consistency. And that's why we avoid dangerous constructs.

Comment: Yes, I know -- there are MS Windows, Apple Mac OSX and there is a Linux. I am Linux guy where is freedom is an wave to glide on it into future. Chaos gave a birth of life while control has been eating it away.

Answer (score 3):

[ *There is a discrepancy between the OP's stated desired output (`10 -1 -6`), and the output produced by the provided `awk` code  (`10 -1 6`). This answer assumes the OP wants the output produces by the provided `awk` code.* ]

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

my %incs_by_sign = ( "+" => 1, "-" => -1 );

# Skip header.
defined(scalar(<>))
   or exit;

my $val = 0;
my $i;
while (<>) {
   my (undef, $sign, $x, $y) = split;

   if (defined($i)) {
      # Backfill the gap.
      for (; $i<$x; ++$i) {
         say join "\t", $i, 0, $val;
      }
   } else {
      $i = $x;
   }

   # Flatten.
   my $inc = $incs_by_sign{$sign};
   for (; $i<=$y; ++$i) {
      $val += $inc;
      say join "\t", $i, $inc, $val;
   }
}
```

As a condensed "one-liner":

```sh
perl -lane'
   BEGIN { $, = "\t"; }
   next if $. == 1;  # Skip header.
   $i //= $F[2];
   print $i++, 0, $val while $i < $F[2];
   my $inc = 0 + ( $F[1] . 1 );
   print $i++, $inc, $val += $inc while $i <= $F[3];
'
```

Output:

```
1       1       1
2       1       2
3       1       3
4       0       3
5       1       4
6       1       5
7       1       6
8       1       7
9       0       7
10      -1      6
11      -1      5
12      -1      4
```

Both solutions assume the input file is sorted by coordinate.

Both the script and the one-liner accept input from the file named by its parameter, or from STDIN if no parameters are provided.

Comment: thnx a lot for the answer. Both solutions work but the only reason why I will accept @polar bear's answer is that yours its a bit complicated for an amateur like me, but I want to came clean that really I appreciate your time and your help.

Comment: @KGee, Will the first coordinate of the first line always be 1? My code is a little bit more complicated because it doesn't make that assumption like the other answer does.

Comment: If there's anything you'd like to me explain, feel free to ask. There are two primary differences: I used C-style loop (which you can read about in the perlsyn perl documentation page) so I wouldn't have to use three different variables for the same thing (`$i` in my answer is known as `$count`, the first foreach loop's `$_`, and the second foreach loop's `$_` in the other answer), and I used a hash lookup instead of the multiple ifs. You should definitely get comfortable with using hashes instead of chains of if statements

Comment: thanks a lot once again!!! The reason why I respond late is that I was trying to understand the logic behind this Perl. I am printing everything I am playing with the values etc ...